# How to import all tables and data from VS to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a website that has 70+ tables. Now I have to live that website. For this I am using appharbor and SQL Server Management Studio. To create tables in SQL Server Management Studio, I click `New Query` then write the definition and then click `Execute query`. Is there a way I can import all 70+ tables into SQL Server Management Studio from Visual Studio?

**Update:**
I am using visual studio 2013. I am working on asp.net MVC. I created SQL Server Database (.mdf) then on left side in Server Explorer window I created tables. Then I created Ado.net entity data model and used the tables.

Comment: How are the tables defined in Visual Studio? (And which version of VS?)

Comment: On SQL Management : right click database -> generate scripts -> next??

Comment: @Richard i updated the question. please have a look

Comment: @brykneval In right click database > tasks > generate scripts > set scripting options > save scripts to specific location / publish web service. I choose publish web service then I click `manage providers` > new . then in web service address I put host name (given in sql server connection options) and username and password.. Then I click available database. It asks for server name, username and password.. How can I put my local VS database over there.

Comment: @IrfanWattoo if you have credentials for database server, choose savescript instead of web service -> new window and run that script on intended database

Comment: @brykneval ok i choose save scripts to a specific location and click next. Now in summary (review your selections) the source contains my sql server database configuration (which is empty) But i want to provide my local database configuration.